# Summarize a metric that's already a rate

Tags: prometheus

We have a metric, let's say `http_requests_total`.  This is generated by multiple pods in a Kubernetes cluster for the one service.  There are also multiple clusters around the world generating the same metric. This also has a custom label called `customer_id` which lets us group the metric by each customer. This is scraped per minute.

We want to see this aggregated across all pods in the service & federated to a central Prometheus, so we have a rule in each Prometheus that generates a new metric called `http_requests_total_rate` which is the result of `sum by(customer_id) (rate(http_requests_total[2m]))`. This rule metric is what we then scrape into the federation Prometheus.

So now we have a nicely rated then summed metric that we can view per-minute global HTTP request counts per minute, per customer by querying `sum by(customer_id) (http_requests_total_rate)`.

The issue is, how can I see a per-day metric from this federated metric?  I can't do any of the normal tricks like `increase(http_requests_total[24h])` or `sum_over_time` because these require a range from a counter, and we already have a rate.

Can this be done with the federated metric that is already a rate?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have access to a rate, requests per minute, and you want a rate, requests per day, as a result, right? And I'm not sure what you mean by summing over time requiring a range from a counter. Are historical minute rates not saved (i.e. you can only see the last reported minute rate)?

Comment: I don't quiet understand but I think you can just take `avg_over_time` of 24h using your range vector, and it will have the same result of creating a new `(rate(http_requests_total[24h]))`